# An SQL query to give cheapest product by each supplier

Tags: sql-server

I need to find the cheapest product from each supplier.
The tables I have are tb_supplier, tb_consumer, tb_offers, tb_requests, tb_transactions, and tb_products.

I have the following code that currently only shows the cheapest product, it's supplier, and the amount. How do I find the cheapest for EVERY supplier?

```
SELECT Tb_Product.Name, Tb_Supplier.Name, Tb_Offers.Price as 'Price'
FROM Tb_Product, Tb_Supplier, Tb_Offers
WHERE Tb_Product.Prod_ID = Tb_Offers.Prod_ID
  AND Tb_Offers.Supp_ID = Tb_Supplier.Supp_ID
  AND Tb_Offers.Price = (SELECT Min(Tb_Offers.Price)
                        FROM Tb_Offers)
```

Thanks

Comment: Make a subquery much as you already have for `min`. Group by supplier name, and join back on supplier name.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a product is offered by several suppliers and each supplier offers several products we have following schema.

```
declare @prod table(id int, name varchar(50))
declare @supplier table(id int, name varchar(50))
declare @offer table(prodId int, supplierId int, price float)

--populate tables
insert @prod (id,name) values
(1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C')

insert @supplier (id,name) values
(1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C')

insert @offer(prodId,supplierId,price) values
(1,1,10),(1,2,8),(2,1,12),(2,3,11),(3,1,15),(3,3,20)

-- use common table expression to sort offers by price
;with cte as (
select prodId, supplierId, price,
row_number() over(partition by prodId order by price) rn
from @offer
)
select prodId, p.name, supplierId, s.name, price --beautify with names
from cte
inner join @prod p on cte.prodId=p.id
inner join @supplier s on cte.supplierId=s.id
where rn = 1 --only first (cheapest) price

--result returned
prodId  name    supplierId  name    price
1       A       2           B       8
2       B       3           C       11
3       C       1           A       15
```

*Side note*: Comma separated list of tables syntax considered obsolete according to **ANSI92**. Just **25 years ago**.